# ngx-editor generete html with styles but angular dosen't render it

Tags: ngx-editor

i have an angular 17 project with ngx-editor, but when i try to render HTML generated it lose all Styles attributes , i tried with  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Non but dosen't work ,
how i fix it?,

```
                        <div  class="editor" style="padding: 5px 0" class="">
                        <ngx-editor-menu [editor]="editor" [toolbar]="toolbar">
                        </ngx-editor-menu>
                        <ngx-editor [editor]="editor" formControlName="body" id="body">
                        </ngx-editor>
                    </div>

                <div class="NgxEditor__Content" [innerHTML]="form.get('body')?.value"></div>
```